# How to write all those logical statements in a more efficient way in Python?

Tags: python, logic

```
i = 20
while (i%2!= 0 or i%3!= 0 or i %  4 != 0 or i %  5 != 0 or
     i %  6 != 0 or i %  7 != 0 or i %  8 != 0 or i %  9 != 0 or
     i % 10 != 0 or i % 11 != 0 or i % 12 != 0 or i % 13 != 0 or
     i % 14 != 0 or i % 15 != 0 or i % 16 != 0 or i % 17 != 0 or
     i % 18 != 0 or i % 19 != 0 or i % 20 != 0):
i+=20
print(i)
```

I want to find LCM of numbers ranging from 1 to 20. This code in itself is efficient (faster than alternatives), but is there any way that computer can recognize the pattern and make all logical statements accordingly?

Comment: _This code in itself is efficient (faster than alternatives)_ Well, for example you don't need checks `i%2 != 0`, `i%4!= 0`, `i%8!=0` if there's `i%16!=0`. More, you just need factorize numbers from 1 to 20 and LCM is multiplication of primes in the power of maximum occurrence, this would be way more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `any`:

```
while any(i % j != 0 for j in range(2, 21)):
```